# MySQL combining 3 tables in query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables.

```
StockinId - all shelfs in location
+---------+----------+-------+
| country | location | bin   |
+---------+----------+-------+
| LV      | AL       | A-1-1 |
| LV      | AL       | A-1-2 |
| LV      | AL       | A-1-3 |
| LV      | AL       | A-1-4 |
| LV      | AL       | A-1-5 |
| LV      | AL       | A-1-6 |
| LV      | AL       | A-1-7 |
| LV      | AL       | A-1-8 |
| LV      | AL       | A-1-9 |
+---------+----------+-------+


Calculated - calculated amount which should be on the shelf 
+-------------------+----------+-------+
| calculated_needed | location | bin   |
+-------------------+----------+-------+
| 2                 | AL       | A-1-1 |
| 4                 | AL       | A-1-2 |
| 15                | AL       | A-1-3 |
| 5                 | AL       | A-1-4 |
| 22                | AL       | A-1-5 |
+-------------------+----------+-------+

Inventory - actual amount counted physically recounting
+--------+----------+-------+---------------+
| amount | location | bin   | item          |
+--------+----------+-------+---------------+
| 2      | AL       | A-1-1 | 2600000741897 |
| 4      | AL       | A-1-2 | 2600000741897 |
| 5      | AL       | A-1-4 | 2600000999045 |
| 22     | AL       | A-1-5 | 2600000998949 |
| 6      | AL       | A-1-6 | 2600000998925 |
| 99     | AL       | A-1-7 | 2600000998871 |
+--------+----------+-------+---------------+
```

I want to create a query where the output would be containing all bins from the `calculated` table and the rows of `inventory` table that have products counted on them even though the bins should be empty aka items have been displaced in real life. The example is visible below. I have tried but do not have the knowledge to do this. I can do a query where i see all the calculated bins with physical and calculated amounts accordingly but i cant get to output the misplaced but counted items on bins that are not in `Calculated` table.

```
+-------+----------------+-------------------+
| bin   | physcal_amount | calculated_amount |
+-------+----------------+-------------------+
| A-1-1 | 2              | 2                 |
| A-1-2 | 4              | 4                 |
| A-1-3 | -              | 15                |
| A-1-4 | 5              | 5                 |
| A-1-5 | 22             | 22                |
| A-1-6 | 6              | -                 |
| A-1-7 | 99             | -                 |
+-------+----------------+-------------------+
```

I sincerely hope i have made the issue clear enough to be understandable.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i got your question right :

`SELECT StockinId.bin, COALESCE(Inventory.amount,'-') as physcal_amount, COALESCE(Calculated.calculated_needed,'-') as calculated_amount 
FROM StockinId 
LEFT JOIN Calculated 
ON StockinId.bin = Calculated.bin 
LEFT JOIN Inventory 
ON StockinId.bin = Inventory.bin
WHERE Calculated.calculated_needed IS NOT NULL
OR Inventory.amount IS NOT NULL`